# Why items in an UL list with `list-inline` bootstrap class goes to newline?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, razor

I have this list and I want to show this inline , I use `list-inline` class, but  the result is not true . 
I don't know why this happened . Thanks for any answer .

**cshtml code** :

```
<ul  style="text-align: center; list-style-type: none;  vertical-align: top;">

                <li>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.SocialNetworks)
                    {
                        <ul class="list-inline" style="text-align:center;list-style-type:none;padding-top:15px;">
                            <li class="col-xs-3">
                                <a class="aFooter" href="@item.SocialLink">
                                    <img class="img-responsive center-block socialIcon" src="@Url.Content(item.SocialIcon.ToString())" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: You need to post the **HTML** output, your code doesn't recreate the issue. [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: You're right . Sorry , My codes are very complicated and very dirty :/ that's why I just added a peace of it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `padding-top: 15px;` at the inside `<li>` tag.

With running [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qsowdLj/).

Answer (score 0):

Try float left to li element

ie, `li{ float: left;}`

Comment: @shimaamini Could you please post the generated HTML with css ? That way community can help you out :)

Comment: sorry for take your time , my code is very dirty :/ I was confused cause I ... , thanks again